# EKS high availability bitnami rabbitmq redelivered flag always true

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, amazon-eks, bitnami

Is it expected in a cloud environment with 3 redundant rabbit nodes that the redelivered flag is always true due to some load balancing mechanism?

Update: This is the Bitnami https://bitnami.com/stack/rabbitmq/containers deployment if that helps